# Spark ML (Dataframe) and dimension reduction

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, dimensionality-reduction

There does not appear to be classes available to perform dimension reduction if using the newer Dataframe APIs (i.e., not RDD). Nor is there any documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html).

Can someone tell me the approach for dimension reduction using classes from spark.ml (Dataframe) packages rather than spark.mllib (RDD)...? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PCA` is available for new ML API. You'll find details in:

- [ML guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#pca)
- API docs ([Scala](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.PCA), [Python](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.PCA))